# Connecting to server with Docker image after running

Tags: docker

After running my docker image the resulting output is:

```
INFO:     Saving vectors to .word_vectors_cache/wiki.en.vec.pt
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

With this said, when I click on the link I get `This site can’t be reached`. I would include my docker file and the command I using to run the image which is `docker run -p 8000:8080 toxic-content-monitoring:0.1`

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# install build utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcc make apt-transport-https ca-certificates build-essential

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR  /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ /usr/src/app
COPY data/ /usr/src/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app"]
```

I need help figuring out how to see the docker image when I click `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Answer (score 0):

To see the exposed URL use this port:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

But if your server is already using the port 8000

Change your docker command to this:

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 toxic-content-monitoring:0.1
```

And then access this URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

This will clear your confusion with docker run command:

```
docker run -p <EXTERNAL_PORT>:<DOCKER_INTERNEL_PORT> toxic-content-monitoring:0.1
```

Comment: Still not working I changed the command to `docker run -p 8081:8000 toxic-content-monitoring:0.1` and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You’re exposing the service on the host port 8000. You might also need to change host binding on uvicorn by setting —host 0.0.0.0 (this is not recommended for production though because it accepts connections on all ips)

Comment: `--host 0.0.0.0` is required in Docker, since the container runs in an isolated network environment; the default binding to `127.0.0.1` binds to the container-private localhost interface, which isn't accessible from outside the container at all.

Comment: It’s not really required because you can specify the IP for the container on the docker managed network. The reason I say it’s not recommended is because a container might connect to several networks (and thus have several IPs), so setting an explicit bind host is always better.